# Are questions about naming a programming language on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

I am sure that asking a question such as *'What should I name my programming language?'* is going to be too broad and opinion-based. But if someone had a more specific question about naming a programming language such as *'Is <name> too similar to any existing programming languages?'* could such questions be accepted?

Comment: Possibly such questions could address the Googleability of language names

Comment: Recent example of this - https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/how-does-the-design-of-a-programming-language-relate-to-its-name
I feel we correctly closed it because the answer was so obviously no. but perhaps it wasn't so obvious to the asker.

Answer (score 20):

## Close as Opinion Based

This site is about the design and implementation of languages. It's not about marketing a language. It's not about SEO or search-ability of a language. All of that is out-of-scope here. Unless the name of your language has a genuine impact on the design of it, it's not on topic (and in 99% of cases, the design of your language determines the name, not the other way around).

Comment: There is a fine line between marketing and SEO which can be self serving and [community building](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/94/285)

Answer (score 3):

[Naming things is hard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBRoCdtZOYg).

Advice about picking names for parts of a language should certainly be accepted. For example *this is called an "affine" type*.

If we accept questions about community building (which I'm not sure is [settled](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/94/285) yet), then it suggests questions like how to go about picking a name for a language should be accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the kind of granularity of naming that the question here is asking about. The question here seems to be just about naming the language(s) (?)